# Configure multiple facebook pages to single bot

Tags: facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, azure-bot-service

[image][image]I am trying to configure 2 facebook pages to single bot using microsoft bot framework. I have added 2 page's id and access tokens in channel configuration by selecting facebook channel. Also, I have kept same webhook call back urls in both pages.

Now, I am able to communicate through only one page where as am getting "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden" error while accessing through other page.

Please suggest what did I wrong and how to fix this issue.

Comment: Which URL gives the 403, in what context?

Comment: While am trying to send message to bot from FB page. Am getting 403 error. i have attached webhook error in my question.

Comment: Basically what you have to do is store PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN for each page and then subscribe the page to your bot(app). Have your subscribed your page to subscribe to the webhook? You can go to your app's webhook settings and then select the page to subscribe your webhook to the page events. Refer to step 9 of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#enable-webhooks